# c# Excel macro error 13 type mismatch after copying data from one worksheet to another

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I am currently working on a web application where users can download an Excel file, fill the file with their data, upload the file and start some calculation.
To do so, the old method was to open user's file and to copy all the data in an array of string then open the Excel calculation file where the macro is and paste the date. It works....
Now, Instead of during that, I use the method Copy().

```
public class ExcelCtrl
    {
        private Excel.Application excelApp = null;
        private Excel.Workbook srcworkbook = null;
        private Excel.Workbook destworkbook = null;

public void excel_init(String srcpath, String destpath)
    {
        //Open Excel
        this.excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        //Open user's file
        this.srcworkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(srcpath);
        Excel.Worksheet srcworksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)srcworkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        //Open calculation file
        this.destworkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(destpath);
        Excel.Worksheet destworksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)destworkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        //Range of copy
        Excel.Range from = srcworksheet.get_Range("A1:Z100");
        Excel.Range to = destworksheet.get_Range("A1:Z100");

        //Copy
        from.Copy(to);

        //Close user's file
        srcworkbook.Close();

        //Open Xla file
        excelApp.Workbooks.Open("someXlaFile.xla");
        excelApp.Workbooks.Open("AnotherXlaFile.xla");  
    }
```

And I use it like this :

```
public static string Calculation1(String InputFileName, String CurDir)
    {
        //The Excel calculation file and its path
        string filename = "CalculationFile.xls";
        string path_server = ExcelCtrl.DossierCalcs + filename;

        ExcelCtrl excel = new ExcelCtrl();

        excel.excel_init(CurDir + "\\" + InputFileName, ExcelCtrl.DossierCalcs + filename);

        //Run the macro : where the problem is
        excel.excel_run("Macro1");

        //The rest is not important
        path_server = CurDir + "\\Resultats - " + InputFileName;

        excel.excel_run("AnotherMacro", path_server);

        excel.excel_close();

        return path_server;
```

So I got an error 13: Type mismatch when I run Macro1 ( I did not put the code for excel_run(), it is just a simple method that calls Application.run()).
I use this code for other calculations and all work fine except this one. Of course, Macro change from one Excel calculation file to another but it works before with the copy paste method and I dont think I should change the VBA code.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Thanks to the mighty printf I think I know where is the problem...

```
2450 If W0 = 1 Then GoTo 2470 Else
MsgBox ("test3")
HB = Worksheets("INPUT_DATA").Range("H_B_souflage") / 1000: HB = HB / NF
MsgBox ("test4")
```

The original code is like that :

```
2450 If W0 = 1 Then GoTo 2470 Else: HB = Worksheets("INPUT_DATA").Range("H_B_souflage") / 1000: HB = HB / NF
```

I just split it after the Else.
When I run Macro1, I have test3 then error 13.

Below is the original method, maybe it can help.

```
public static string Calculation1(String InputFileName, String CurDir)
{
        //the string used to store the date
        string[] my_input_array = new string[21];

        //Open user's file
        ExcelCtrl.excel_init(CurDir + "\\" + InputFileName);
        //Call the method to initialize the array
        my_input_array = file_input_copy(my_input_array);
        ExcelCtrl.excel_close();

        //Open calculation file
        ExcelCtrl.excel_init(path_server);
        //Call the method to paste the data to the calculation file
        file_input_write(my_input_array);

        //run macro : the same as above
        ExcelCtrl.appExcel.Run("macro1");

        //the rest is not important
        path_server = CurDir + "\\Resultats - " + InputFileName; 
        ExcelCtrl.appExcel.Run("AnotherMacro", path_server);
        ExcelCtrl.excel_close();
        return path_server;
```

You may notice that excel_init is different (it was a static class before) but I dont think that the problem come from this class.

The code to initialize the array string :
Sorry if you have to read a lot of code. I think this two method below are not very important, just a classic while loop. But I want to put it here because of the method : convert.toDouble()

```
    private static string[] file_input_copy(string[] my_input_array)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int row = 5;
        string str = "E" + row;

        while (i < my_input_array.Length)
        {
            str = "E" + row;
            my_input_array[i] = ExcelCtrl.excel_getValue(str);
            //excel_getValue is just a method that return get_Range(cellname).get_Value().ToString()
            row++;
            if (row == 23)
                row++;
            i++;
        }
        return my_input_array;
    }
```

And the code to paste :

```
    private static void file_input_write(string[] my_input_array)
    {
        Excel.Range aRange;
        int i = 0;
        int row = 5;
        string str = "E" + row;

        while (i < my_input_array.Length)
        {
            str = "E" + row;
            aRange = ExcelCtrl.objsheet.get_Range(str, str);
            try
            {
                aRange.Value2 = Convert.ToDouble(my_input_array[i]);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                aRange.Value2 = my_input_array[i];
            }
            row++;
            if (row == 23)
                row++;
            i++;
        }
    }
```

When I use this code to copy paste the data, it works...
What I don't understand is that those two methods are used in other calculations class (with a slight variation) to copy the data and when I change for what I did, it works.
Maybe those two methods are doing something copy() is not doing.

**EDIT 2**

The cell H_B_souflage is equal to =Hauteur_prod(PREFmax) and PREFmax is equal to !DATA_ALL!E7. DATA_ALL is a sheet where I copy paste user's data. E7 is the problematic cell.
The code for Hauteur_prod() :

```
Function Hauteur_prod(Production)
Dim prod(10), haut(10)
For i = 1 To 8
prod(i) = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("Prod_t_hm").Cells(i)
haut(i) = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("Height_m").Cells(i)
Next
If Production >= prod(8) Then
ElseIf Production >= prod(8) Then
Hauteur_prod = haut(8)
ElseIf Production >= prod(7) Then
Hauteur_prod = haut(7)
ElseIf Production >= prod(6) Then
Hauteur_prod = haut(6)
ElseIf Production >= prod(5) Then
Hauteur_prod = haut(5)
ElseIf Production >= prod(4) Then
Hauteur_prod = haut(4)
ElseIf Production >= prod(3) Then
Hauteur_prod = haut(3)
ElseIf Production >= prod(2) Then
Hauteur_prod = haut(2)
ElseIf Production >= prod(1) Then
Hauteur_prod = haut(1)
Else
Hauteur_prod = haut(1)
End If
Hauteur_prod = Hauteur_prod * 1000 'mm
End Function
```

Prod_t_hm and Height_m are array of integers with 8 values.

Just like what I said in comment. The macro from Excel calculation file with default values works. When I upload the data file with my test values, for instance I put 39 inside cell E7 and use my code to copy my data to the calculation file without running the macro. Then I run manually the macro by openning my Excel file, it crashed with error 13 but after changing the cell E7 to, let's say 40, the macro works.

Comment: What line do you get the error on?

Comment: On excel.excel_run("Macro1");  excel_run is just a method that contains this.excelApp.Run(macro);

Comment: Error 13 Type Mismatch is native to VBA. I suspect there's some type mismatch between a value in the excel file and the variable in Macro1 that this value is being parsed into. I don't see anything wrong with your C# code.

Comment: Can you share what is in `Macro1`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Sorry, I can't really share it... I edited my question with one line from Macro1 (where I get the error). I hope there are no errors after this one.

Comment: The code you shared is good enough :) `HB = Worksheets("INPUT_DATA").Range("H_B_souflage") / 1000: HB = HB / NF` How is `HB` Declared?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Sorry, took me some time to look at it (very new to VBA) and I asked my tutor, he said HB is not declared... Btw, what does ':' means in VBA, he doesn't know either

Comment: `1` ":" is used when you want to put two or more lines of code in one line `2`: You will get a `Error 13 Type Mismatch` when the variable or property isn't of the correct type. For example, a variable that requires an integer value can't accept a string value unless the whole string can be recognized as an integer.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I get it now I guess. So since HB is not declared before, HB takes the type when it is initialized, just like variable in... JavaScript ? I tried to replace `Worksheets("INPUT_DATA").Range("H_B_souflage")` by its value (2000) and It works (I get test4). But that doesn't explain why with the old method it works without changing the VBA code.

Comment: Also, by removing `/1000` it works too. So I'm guessing `Worksheets("INPUT_DATA").Range("H_B_souflage")` returns something that can't be cast to a integer. But again that doesn't explain why it works before...

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `HB` has not been declared as `Integer?` Declare it s `Long` or `Double`. Also see what does the value `Worksheets("INPUT_DATA").Range("H_B_souflage")` returns? Ideally the line should be written as  `HB = Val(Worksheets("INPUT_DATA").Range("H_B_souflage").Value) / 1000`

Comment: @SiddharthRout You need the key word `Dim HB As type`right? I searched in the entire code and it is not here. `Worksheets("INPUT_DATA").Range("H_B_souflage")` returns 2000 (in fact the cell `H_B_souflage` is equal to a function that takes one parameter and returns an integer value. I can put the code for this function if it may help. Also, I tried what you said and I still get the same error at the same line.

Comment: Do this split `HB = Worksheets("INPUT_DATA").Range("H_B_souflage") / 1000: HB = HB / NF` in two lines `HB = Worksheets("INPUT_DATA").Range("H_B_souflage") / 1000` and then in the next line `HB = HB / NF` NOw can you tell me which line is giving the error?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes, this is what I was doing. And the error comes from the first line. But when I replace ` Worksheets("INPUT_DATA").Range("H_B_souflage")` by its value from the cell ( 2000) I have `HB = 2000 / 1000` then I have no error and `HB / NF`works too.

Comment: `I can put the code for this function if it may help` I would love that :D

Comment: @SiddharthRout When I run the macro manually from the Excel calculation file (without user's date; with default data) it works without problem. So, after the `copy()` I saved the Excel file and ran the macro manually (instead of during it in C#) again and this time I got the error 13. But when I replace the problematic cell with the same value (I just rewrite it) and run the macro manually, this time it works (I don't know if I'm clear...)

Comment: @SiddharthRout LOL since rewriting the value makes the macro to work... I change a little bit my Calculation1 method. After copying data from user's file to calculation file, I add `string val = excel.excel_getvalue("E", 7);` and `excel.excel_setvalue("E", 7, val);` before calling the macro and it works... I still don't know why, guess magic. Thank you, by talking to you it helped me very much :)